# Are there groups $G$ such that: $\forall x,y\in G:x\bar ky=y\bar kx$ for some nontrivial $\bar k\in G$?

Tags: group-theory

By analogy with the abelian groups, are there groups $G$ such that:
$$\forall x,y\in G:x\bar ky=y\bar kx$$
for some *nontrivial* $\bar k\in G$?

Comment: By setting $x=e$ you can see that we would require $\bar{k} \in Z(G)$. But then we would have $x\bar{k}y = y\bar{k}x \iff \bar{k}xy = \bar{k}yx \iff xy = yx$ for all $x,y \in G$. So in fact $G$ must be abelian.

Comment: $(\forall x,y)(\exists \bar{k})$ or $(\exists \bar{k})(\forall x,y)$?

Comment: The second one, @JeremyRickard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $z \in G$, non-trivial and $xzy=yzx$ for all $x,y \in G$, then (take $y=1$) $z \in Z(G)$ and hence $xy=yx$ for all $x,y \in G$, that is $G$ is abelian...